# Confusing with getGlobalVisibleRect, different values

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, objectanimator

I'm try to zoom a FrameLayout with the following example from der android developers site: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

My concrete Problem, in the first time the animation is right, is expand from the thumbView, in the second time the animation comes from 'somewhere' (middle/top to the center).

i have nearly the same, the differents are, i have an Framelayout instead an ImageView and i extract the function to minimize the View back in an extra Method. now thats looks like so:

```
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView) {

    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // here i building my custome layout

    startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    findViewById(R.id.container)
            .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x + 15, -globalOffset.y + 60);

    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
            > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {

        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {

        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set
            .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                    startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                    startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
            startScale, 1f)).with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                    View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;
}
```

the startBounds Variable is global, cause i need this to know where the position is for the minimize process. Here the minimize Method:

```
    private void minimizeViewFromThumb(final View thumbView) {
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                    mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
                }

                AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                set.play(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                            .with(ObjectAnimator
                                    .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                            View.Y,startBounds.top))
                            .with(ObjectAnimator
                                    .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                            View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                            .with(ObjectAnimator
                                    .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                            View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
                set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
                set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {


                thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }
            });
            set.start();
            mCurrentAnimator = set;
}
```

if i debug this whole process i can see that the method getGlobalVisibleRect from the method zoomViewFromThumb give me another value.

if i debug the line

```
finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
```

in the first time the two parameters are 0 and -60 and in the second time (after minimize and recreate there are 15 and 360.

i have no idea why thats happen.

i have try to set the View.X and View.Y parameter append from the given thumbView, i have try to work with constant Values for the View.X, View.Y parameter in the ObjectAnimator but nothing fix my problem.

now please help me.

Greets Manu

**1. EDIT:** the fail is on Android Version 4.1.2 i have test it in the emulator with Android 4.0 and there it works fine

**2. EDIT:** Here are the xml files, the first one is the xml File that representing my main Activity (with the animation), the second one represent the TableLayout what i push in the FrameLayout of the main xml. (Please notice, currently I'm at work and i have no access to the original, now these xml files are good as far I can remember)

the first

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relZoom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameZoomOne"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameZoomTwo"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="408dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerTwo"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="408dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the second

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Column 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="Column 3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:text="Column 4"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**3. EDIT:** correct the xml file and now adding the Activity:

```
public class SinglePlayerSp extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private final Context mContext = this;
    private boolean mBackZoomOne = false;
    private FrameLayout frameZoomOne;
    private FrameLayout frameZoomTwo;
    private static Animator mCurrentAnimatorOne;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;
    private float startScaleOne;
    private static Animator mCurrentAnimatorTwo;
    private float startScaleTwo;
    private Rect startBoundsOne;
    private Rect startBoundsTwo;
    private static View lastViewOne;
    private static View lastViewTwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);

        frameZoomOne = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameZoomOne);
        frameZoomTwo = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameZoomTwo);
        frameZoomOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        frameZoomTwo.setOnClickListener(this);

        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);

        cardItems = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(CARD_ITEMS);

        java.util.Collections.shuffle(cardItems);

    }

private void flipCard(boolean playerOneDeck, final int selectionFromPlayer, final boolean result)
    {
        Card cardItemOne = null;

            if (oneCards.get(0) != null)
            {
                cardItemOne = oneCards.get(0);
            }

            if (!mBackZoomOne)
            {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in,
                        R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out).replace(
                        R.id.frameZoomOne, new CardBackFragment()).commit();
                mBackZoomOne = true;
            }
            else
            {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in,
                        R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out).replace(
                        R.id.frameZoomOne,
                        CardFrontFragment.newInstance(cardItemPlayerOne, selectionFromPlayer, playerOneDeck)).commit();
                mBackZoomOne = false;

                zoomViewOneFromThumb(frameZoomOne, cardItemOne);
            }
    }

private void zoomViewOneFromThumb(final View thumbView, final Card cardItem)
    {
        if (mCurrentAnimatorOne != null)
        {
            mCurrentAnimatorOne.cancel();
        }

        lastViewOne = thumbView;
        View.getDefaultSize(0, 0);
        final FrameLayout expandFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_front_clickable, null);

        TableRow rowOne = (TableRow) layout.findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
        rowOne.setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView cardone = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView cardtwo = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView cardthree = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView cardfour = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        Locale locale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

        cardone.setText(cardItem.TextOne());
        cardtwo.setText(cardItem.getTextTwo());
        cardthree.setText(cardItem.getTextThree());
        cardfour.setText(cardItem.TextFour());

        expandFrameLayout.addView(layout);

        startBoundsOne = new Rect();
        final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
        final Point globalOffset = new Point();

        thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBoundsOne);
        findViewById(R.id.containerSp).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
        startBoundsOne.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
        finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x + 15, -globalOffset.y + 50);

        if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBoundsOne.width()
                / startBoundsOne.height())
        {
            startScaleOne = (float) startBoundsOne.height() / finalBounds.height();
            float startWidth = startScaleOne * finalBounds.width();
            float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBoundsOne.width()) / 2;
            startBoundsOne.left -= deltaWidth;
            startBoundsOne.right += deltaWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            startScaleOne = (float) startBoundsOne.width() / finalBounds.width();
            float startHeight = startScaleOne * finalBounds.height();
            float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBoundsOne.height()) / 2;
            startBoundsOne.top -= deltaHeight;
            startBoundsOne.bottom += deltaHeight;
        }

        thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
        expandFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        expandFrameLayout.setPivotX(0f);
        expandFrameLayout.setPivotY(0f);

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.X, startBoundsOne.left, finalBounds.left)).with(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.Y, startBoundsOne.top, finalBounds.top)).with(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.SCALE_X, startScaleOne, 1f)).with(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleOne, 1f));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                mCurrentAnimatorOne = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
            {
                mCurrentAnimatorOne = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimatorOne = set;
        startScaleFinal = startScaleOne; // with this or without this, i have the same problem
    }

private void minimizeViewOne(final View expandFrameLayout)
    {
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.X, startBoundsOne.left)).with(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.Y, startBoundsOne.top)).with(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal)).with(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandFrameLayout, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                lastViewOne.setAlpha(1f);
                expandFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCurrentAnimatorOne = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
            {
                lastViewOne.setAlpha(1f);
                expandFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCurrentAnimatorOne = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimatorOne = set;
    }
}
```

OK that's now the full code. At the End is an onClick Method, in there I receive user actions. from there I call the minimizeView Method, then some checks, after this I call the flipCard. That's all.

Comment: do you have any news? could you try my code? if its not working, i would need some other details of your code, because know i have a good undestanding of the overall

Comment: sorry for not responding you. yesterday I have try it, but it is the same issue still. I'm not sure it is because the TableLayout that I use for the FrameLayout. But I have no ClickListern on the ExpandedFrameLayout. I trigger the minimize from an other event. The User can Click on an Row that is in the ExpandedFrameLayout, after this I minimize the last setted View. Thats works fine but in the second time I would like to zoome a new thumb, then comes the Error. What other Information you need?

Comment: That makes sense for me. Can you post the layout file?

Comment: @CarlosRobles please take notice, I have added the two xml files, but currently i have access to the original files, now these are representing it good as possible

Comment: im trying to build it, but im missing to much stuff to understand your system. when you say `// here i building my custome layout` i dont know what are you doing, i can figure it out, but im figuring out to much, and all this is too relevant

Comment: actually, it will be great if you post your implied classes. this couldnt be much code, and it is the onlu way that anybody can understand what you have

Comment: @CarlosRobles please see my start post I have updated it.

Comment: you say that that's the full code,but it isnt.As i say we miss relevant parts,like views,and your problem is view related,so its impossible to help.i dont know for instance what is containerSp,fragment_card_front_clickable, CARD_ITEMS,cardItems,the class Card,oneCards,or even startScaleFinal that is never declared,but there are instead some other declared variables that are never used. When you have a question that is logic-related, you can post faithful pseudo code and is ok,if its about a bug, you have to post real code. this kind of code is none of them.please help yourself and review this

Answer (score 4):

**As per google Developer:**

getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect r, Point globalOffset);

If some part of this view is not clipped by any of its parents, then return that area in r in global (root) coordinates.

ex:
  thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);

here suppose thumbview has width of 100 and height 75  and marging from left and and top 16 and 51 respectively this method store value in startBound(Rect)  as  left 16 , top 51 , right 16+100 = 116 , bottom 51+75 = 126. i.e. (16 , 51 , 116 , 126)

Answer (score 0):

im not sure where you are assigning the event to close the view. but i would say that the point that is causing the error, is where you read some variables such  as  `startScaleFinal = startScale;` that has to be done **before the enlarge animation start**  and  proabaly others.

ill post my full working example with the diferent functions, and frameviews:
It is working perfectly.

activity:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.animationsdemo;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

/**
 * A sample showing how to zoom an image thumbnail to full-screen, by animating the bounds of the
 * zoomed image from the thumbnail bounds to the screen bounds.
 *
 * <p>In this sample, the user can touch one of two images. Touching an image zooms it in, covering
 * the entire activity content area. Touching the zoomed-in image hides it.</p>
 */
public class ZoomActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * Hold a reference to the current animator, so that it can be canceled mid-way.
     */
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

    /**
     * The system "short" animation time duration, in milliseconds. This duration is ideal for
     * subtle animations or animations that occur very frequently.
     */
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();
    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    float startScale;
    FrameLayout expandedImageView;

    float startScaleFinal  ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);

        // Hook up clicks on the thumbnail views.

        final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
        thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });

        final View thumb2View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_2);
        thumb2View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(thumb2View, R.drawable.image2);
            }
        });

        // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    }


    private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
        // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it immediately and proceed with this one.
        if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
            mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
        }

        // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
     expandedImageView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);


        // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail, and the
        // final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container view. Also
        // set the container view's offset as the origin for the bounds, since that's
        // the origin for the positioning animation properties (X, Y).
        thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
        findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
        startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
        finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

        // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final bounds using the
        // "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable stretching during the animation.
        // Also calculate the start scaling factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).

        if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
                > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
            // Extend start bounds horizontally
            startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
            float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
            float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
            startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
            startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
        } else {
            // Extend start bounds vertically
            startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
            float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
            float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
            startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
            startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
        }

        // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation begins,
        // it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the thumbnail.
        thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations to the top-left corner of
        // the zoomed-in view (the default is the center of the view).
        expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
        expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

        // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and scale properties
        // (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set
                .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left,
                        finalBounds.left))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top,
                        finalBounds.top))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimator = set;

        // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down to the original bounds
        // and show the thumbnail instead of the expanded image.
        startScaleFinal = startScale;
   expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                minimizeViewFromThumb(thumbView);
              }
        });
    }
    private void minimizeViewFromThumb(final View thumbView) {  

        // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down to the original bounds
        // and show the thumbnail instead of the expanded image.


                if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                    mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
                }

                // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel, back to their
                // original values.
                AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                set
                        .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
                set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
                set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }
                });
                set.start();
                mCurrentAnimator = set;


    }
}
```

layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/message_zoom_touch_expand" />

        <!-- This is an example layout containing thumbnail image buttons that, when pressed,
             zoom in to show more detail. All of the zooming and animation logic is in
             the ZoomActivity class. -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- These buttons don't have any decorations (3D bevel, etc.), but it's still
                 important to show feedback on touch or focus. The custom
                 "ToughHighlightImageButton" ImageButton subclass helps achieve this by drawing
                 the standard system "pressed" and "focused" overlay upon user interaction. -->

                  <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
 android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/thumb_button_2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
 android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This initially-hidden ImageView will hold the expanded/zoomed version of the
         images above. Without transformations applied, it takes up the entire screen.
         To achieve the "zoom" animation, this view's bounds are animated from the
         bounds of the thumbnail buttons above, to its final laid-out bounds. The implementation
         of this animation is in the ZoomActivity class. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

</FrameLayout>
```